# Sailjs-Waterline: Serialize, Parse and initialize an Model

Tags: json, node.js, performance, sails.js, waterline

Let's assume that I found user using next command:

```
User.findOne(id).exec(function(err, user){
  redis.set(JSON.stringify(user), id);
})
```

After that I'm loading from redis my object

```
redis.get(id, function(err, reply){
  if(!err && reply) {
    var user = JSON.parse(reply);

    // here methods like user.save() or any of defined manually by developer is unavailable

    // 
  } else {
    ..
  }
})
```

User model example:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes    : {
    // Simple attribute:
    // name: 'STRING',

    // Or for more flexibility:
    // phoneNumber: {
    //  type: 'STRING',
    //  defaultValue: '555-555-5555'
    // }

    email : {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true
    },

    // ... 

    verifyPass: function(pass, callback) {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      if (callback) {
        return Password.compare(pass, obj.local.password, callback);
      }
      return Password.compareSync(pass, obj.local.password);
    },

    // retrieve profile for sending to front end
    getProfile: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      var profile = {};

      profile.id = obj.id;
      // ...
      return profile;
    },
```

I need all of that methods to be work whenever I parse waterline model from json. Is there a way to initialize it without triggering db at all. Also would be nice if I could to call user.save().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no documented public API for this unfortunately, but you can use,

```
var user = new PersonCollection._model(values, {showJoins: true});
```

See how that works for you!